# Métodos OnCreate

Tags: java, android

Tengo estos 2 métodos, sin embargo el último no funciona, mi código compila pero cuando doy click en el botón simplemente no pasa nada. ¿Saben cómo lo puedo solucionar?

```
public class MapsActivity extends FragmentActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback {

    Button siguiente;
    private GoogleMap mMap;
    private Marker marcador;
    double lat = 0.0;
    double lng = 0.0;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);
        // Obtain the SupportMapFragment and get notified when the map is ready to be used.
        SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
                .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
        mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
    }


    protected void onCreate1(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);

        siguiente = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_next_services);

        siguiente.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                Intent siguiente = new Intent(MapsActivity.this, SelectServicesActivity.class);
                startActivity(siguiente);
            }
        });
    }
```

Gracias

Comment: Odalis, debes tener ùnicamente un método onCreate().

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El método `onCreate1()` no es un método llamado durante la construcción de la activity, por lo tanto no es válido para lo que deseas.
Debes usar únicamente el método `onCreate()`.

```
    public class MapsActivity extends FragmentActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback {

        Button siguiente;
        private GoogleMap mMap;
        private Marker marcador;
        double lat = 0.0;
        double lng = 0.0;

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);


            siguiente = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_next_services);

            siguiente.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {

                    Intent siguiente = new Intent(MapsActivity.this, SelectServicesActivity.class);
                    startActivity(siguiente);
                }
            });


            // Obtain the SupportMapFragment and get notified when the map is ready to be used.
            SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
                    .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
            mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
        }

    //metodo no valido.
      /*  protected void onCreate1(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);

            siguiente = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_next_services);

            siguiente.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {

                    Intent siguiente = new Intent(MapsActivity.this, SelectServicesActivity.class);
                    startActivity(siguiente);
                }
            });
        }*/
}
```

Answer (score 1):

El problema que tienes es que `onCreate1` no es un método estándard del ciclo de vida de las activities de Android. Por tanto, no se llama de forma implicita en la creación en del `FragmentActivity`.

De este modo, el evento `OnClickListener` nunca es establecido en el botón ya que ese código no se está ejecutando y, como es de esperar, al pulsar el botón no se ejecuta nada.

Para establecer el evento en el botón debes ponerlo dentro del `onCreate` "original", que si se llama en la creación del `FragmentActivity`, o bien dentro de un método que se llame desde dicho `onCreate`.

Prueba con este código:

```
public class MapsActivity extends FragmentActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback {

    Button siguiente;
    private GoogleMap mMap;
    private Marker marcador;
    double lat = 0.0;
    double lng = 0.0;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);
        // Obtain the SupportMapFragment and get notified when the map is ready to be used.
        SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
                .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
        mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);    

        siguiente = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_next_services);    
        siguiente.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                Intent siguiente = new Intent(MapsActivity.this, SelectServicesActivity.class);
                startActivity(siguiente);
    }

}
```